copyright in teaching
Suppose I am a teacher of a foreign language. If I do not cite the source of my knowledge of that language in the material I teach my students, am I violating intellectual-property and copyright? (I mean, if I only use other people's ideas and knowledge for teaching, not copy their words and writings.)

"Citing your sources" is totally irrelevant to copyright. In the early 2000s, everyone on Napster "cited their sources" by naming the files like Metallica - Enter Sandman.mp3 so you knew it was a song by Metallica instead of the user's own original music. It was still copyright infringement...

@kaya3 Not quite true. Attribution can be relevant to the “bad faith” analysis that feeds into the first prong of a fair-use analysis. See, e.g., Rogers v. Koons, 960 F.2d 301, 309 (2d Cir. 1992) (holding that removal of copyright attribution “suggests bad faith in defendant's use of plaintiff's work, and militates against a finding of fair use”).
